# Facebook SDK call unsuccessful on document ready

Tags: jquery, facebook

If I call a Facebook SDK function directly from an onclick from an anchor tag it works, but if I trigger it through jQuery's `$(document).ready()`, it stops after first alert and does not throw any errors.

```
function lfr() {
    alert('test if loaded'); /* This works in both calls. */

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            /* Do something - this only works through anchor tag onclick call. */
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wire in your event handlers inside of the window.fbAsyncInit() function so the Facebook JavaScript SDK has had a chance to fully initialize.

So at the comment section Facebook's documentation generally shows  `// Additional initialization code here` you should place your event handler hook up code.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ for more information.

FWIW, window.fbAsyncInit and the `$(document).ready()` are not the same event nor do they occur at the same time.

Comment: thanks. if i add the code to the fbAsyncInit() function, this time i can not make sure if the other elements are loaded outside of Facebook SDK. (other jscript elements on the original page) - i guess there is no event check to make sure both document is ready and facebook init is complete at the same time.

basically, i am writing a javascript variable on the page on a certain occasion, i want to be able to check when the doc is ready and facebook is loaded, if that certain variable is set and make an api call to facebook. am i making it too confusing ?

Comment: Just put the jQuery .ready call inside of the fbAsyncInit().  That's where I put mine most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Because it hasn't had time to connect to Facebook yet. Try this:

```
if (response.status === 'connected') {
  /* Do something - this only works through anchor tag onclick call. */
} 
else {
  alert('not conected');
}
```

You'll see that the second alert will be shown.

Comment: nope the facebook call is not even made i think. i do a alert(response.status) even before the IF block, but i get nothing. However it works perfectly if i call it from <a onclick="lfr();">test</a>

Answer (score 0):

Here check the facebook documentation on jQuery implementation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
  $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function(){
    FB.init({
      appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
      channelUrl: '//yourapp.com/channel.html',
    });     
    $('#loginbutton,#feedbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
    FB.getLoginStatus(updateStatusCallback);
  });
});
```